# Quick formula rearranging

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, mathematical-physics

I'm having problems rearranging this formula to solve for c, could someone lend a hand please. It's a physics formula for projectile motion.

```
dy = 0.5*acc * (dx / (c*speed))^2 + (sqrt(1-c^2)*speed) * (dx/c*speed))
```

so far I have:

```
(dy*(c^2)) - (sqrt(1-(c^2))*dx*c) = (0.5*acc*(dx^2)) / speed^2
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have an equation with some polynomial of $c$ added to the square root of some other polynomial of $c$ (here, the latter is proportional to $\sqrt{1-c^2}$ then you can solve for $c$ by moving the square root alone to the right side of the equality and getting the other terms all on the left, then squaring.  In this case that gives you a quadratic equation in $c$ to solve, which is easy enough.

But if you also note that $\frac{dy}{dy}$ is the speed, then in fact the quadratic terms cancel and you can solve a linear equation for $c$.

Comment: Thanks for answering Mark, I got rid of the sqrt(1 - c^2) and am now left with:    
-c^2 + c^4 + (dy^2)*(c^4)/dx^2 - dy*a*(c^2) = - 0.25*(a^2)*(dx^2)/(speed^4).   
Sadly dx, dy and speed are independent so it wouldn't turn out to be linear, I'm not sure where to go from here now, any help would be greatly appreciated.